# Как пропустить unauthorized access exception

Tags: c#, исключения

Подскажите как мне пропустить файл после получения `unauthorized access exception` и продолжить действия?

```
 try {
     string[] allFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dr.Name, "*.azz", 
             SearchOption.AllDirectories);
     foreach(string ts in allFoundFiles) {
         //Копирую на флешку тут
     }
 } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
     Console.Write("UnAuthorizedAccessException: Unable to access file. ");
 }
```

Comment: Run program as Administrator

Comment: Унесите конструкцию try-catch внутрь блока foreach

Comment: @Monk на allFoundFiles  ругается

Comment: @Monk а если исключение при получении имён файлов ? здесь нужно права устанавливать .